# Where or how I can get the full list of C# reserved words/methods/namespaces/... for autocomplete

Tags: c#, reflection, autocomplete

I'm doing an autocomplete editor for C# language, and need to get all the words/methods/namespaces/proprieties in C#.
Didn't found anything useful in google.
Also tried with reflection but can't get all items like namespaces after System or other namespaces.

Is there a dictionary with all this on internet, or is there a method to do it with reflection?

for exemple:
User is typing System.

The autocomplete found the System as a namespace and showing all the types/methods and namespaces inside it.

or user is typing Bitmap (if I will not find the Bitmap as a root type, then I will try all the combinations of the using XXX.YYY, like XXX.YYY.Bitmap...)

Thanks

P.S. Please don't recommend me MSDN because I already know about it and this will be the last and worst option, to parse recursively all information on MSDN and save it in a database.

Comment: There is a difference between the C# keywords and the massive set of libraries in .NET.  You'll probably need to search both.

Answer (score 2):

As per @Steve Wellens' comment, there is difference between C# and .NET type names. You have two very different problems to deal with:-

1. Gaining knowledge of C# - will allow your editor to know about C# keywords, etc. This can be found in the [C# language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), as per @Cody Gray's answer. This does not vary according the context of the particular file you are editing (unless you want your editor to have the option to be able to restrict to older version of C# in which case you will need to build in knowledge of previous versions of the spec).
2. Gaining knowledge of the types available in the current editing context. For this, you need to know which namespaces have been declared in `using` statements in the current file and which libraries have been referenced by the project containing the current file. There is no point trying to find out all this information globally for every single library available since the amount of information will be too huge and continuously changing. You could, perhaps, build in knowledge of all type names available in the GAC. In the case of a partial typename, e.g. `Bitmap`, a simple implementation would use the `using` statements contained in the file to attempt to determine which type name is being referred to by examining the relevant assemblies referenced by the project containing the current file (conflicts can occur and will need user resolution, e.g. prefixing the partial type name with some more elements of the actual namespace). This is how the Visual Studio editor works. A richer implementation can examine *all* assemblies referenced by the project containing the current file plus all those contained in the GAC and, if required, suggest either addition of the full name space to the type name or the addition of a `using` statement. This is how Resharper works.

Comment: Actually its a runtime compiler and it have only one or two references (System.Core), its just for quick making operations on images. I was thinking already of making a database from MSDN, but its a tedious task, making the parser of the web pages, for each type/namespace/method and that's why I also asked if somebody maybe knows already of an existing database of all the information for a C# autocompleter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the MSDN documentation, for both the [.NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx) and the [C# language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kx37x362)? This is the closest you'll come to a "directory with all this on [the] internet".

You might also peruse the [C# language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx).

Comment: Actually was thinking of making of a parser for msdn and save all this in database (all the keywords). But I decided to ask here if there is a simpler way to do this (maybe with reflection), or there is already a database with all those keywords before doing this tedious parser.